# How can one completely disable explorer's jump lists in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, jumplist

I never right click on a minimized window in the taskbar for any other purpose than closing it. Seeing a massive list of irrelevant items taller than 1000px in height whenever I right click on an explorer window is becoming quite annoying. Is there any method of nuking this functionality from my system completely?

Comment: Right click and unpin Desktops, Downloads etc. Then remove the other frequent folders list.

Comment: That also removes the items from quick access which I do not want to have happen.

Answer (score -1):

## To disable Jump Lists COMPLETELY (not just clear them)

**(1)** Go to one of the following places:

- Either the address bar of any Windows Explorer window,
- Or the "Start > Run" box,
- Or the Start menu's "search box"

**(2)** Paste in the below path (the text between the quotes) and hit Enter.  It's a hidden folder so you can't navigate to it by clicking.

```
"%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations"
```

**(3)** You will see a bunch of files.  Each one corresponds to a program. [This](http://forensicartifacts.com/2011/09/jump-list-appids/) website can tell you which program corresponds to each file.  Whichever Jump List you want to kill, do the following step to that corresponding file.  I personally hate ALL Jump Lists and kill them ALL.

**(4)** Open each file with a plain text editor like Notepad or Notepad++.  Delete all contents so each file is 0 bytes.  Close the file(s).  Now right-click the file(s).  Click Properties.  Turn on the "Read Only" checkbox.  Click Apply and Ok.

**(5)** Restart your computer.